# httpd.conf file vhost settings

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I try to fix httpd.conf file vhost settings, however there is not much information on web to find on my case. When apaceh updated on my server, httpd.conf file settings are changing. Now my website gives /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi error. You can check with biletme.com. Setting are like this on this file: (Root of website is home/wwwbiletme/public_html)

```
##################################################
#
# Define default vhosts for shared IPs
#
##################################################
##################################################
<VirtualHost 95.179.142.199:80>
ServerName 95.179.142.199
ServerAlias www.biletme.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerAdmin ************
<Directory "/var/www/html">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<IfModule suphp_module>
suPHP_UserGroup nobody nobody
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
##################################################
##################################################
#
# Define default vhosts for unbound IPs
#
##################################################
##################################################
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.biletme.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerAdmin ***********
<Directory "/var/www/html">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<IfModule suphp_module>
suPHP_UserGroup nobody nobody
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
##################################################
```

Comment: Well according to that configuration file, the DocumentRoot is /var/www/html not /home/wwwbiletme/public_html....maybe that's your problem ?

Comment: Thank you Andre, I tried that, then it gives 403 forbidden error.

Comment: Are you sure the user that start Apache have enough rights to read those directory ?

Comment: Can you add some version information ? From what to what ? What MPM are you using ?